# How to use whereEqualTo() and orderBy() in a Firebase Firestore query?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following collection in Firestore. All the documents are similar:

[image]

I am trying to run the following query on it:

```java
orders = new ArrayList<>();
Log.d("cs50", "email = " + email);
database.collection("Orders").whereEqualTo("Donor", email).whereEqualTo("isFulfilled", false).orderBy("timestamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING).get()
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                Log.d("cs50", "snapshots.size() = " + queryDocumentSnapshots.size());
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                    orders.add(documentSnapshot.getId());
                    Log.d("cs50", "onSuccess() orders.size() = " + orders.size());
                }
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
        Log.e("cs50", "Error getting orders", e);
    }
});

notifyDataSetChanged();
```

I get the following output in my logcat:

```
2020-09-21 20:41:54.736 9560-9560/com.example.treeapp D/cs50: email = donor40@gmail.com
2020-09-21 20:41:55.876 9560-9560/com.example.treeapp D/cs50: snapshots.size() = 0
```

The query isn't returning any document snapshot, as you can see from the logcat.

My guess is that I may be using the wrong type of `Direction.DESCENDING` in `orderBy`. It's pretty likely I'm wrong. The IDE gives three options for  `Direction.DESCENDING`: `Query.Direction.DESCENDING`, `OrderBy.Direction.DESCENDING` and `StructuredQuery.Direction.DESCENDING`. As you can see, I'm using `Query.Direction.DESCENDING`. The other two types give an error in the IDE.

I don't understand what exactly is going wrong. I don't get any error messages in my logcat, so there's no problem with security rules. And as you can see from the logcat output, the query actually runs, it just returns an empty `queryDocumentSnapshots`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The document field for the filter is called "fulfilled", but you are using "isFulfilled" to filter it.  That won't work at all.  You must use the same name of the actual field.

```
database
    .collection("Orders")
    .whereEqualTo("Donor", email)
    .whereEqualTo("fulfilled", false)
    .orderBy("timestamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING).get()
```

Comment: Thank you. I should have used `@PropertyName` on all the fields.